# [UIFont CacheKey count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to use `NSMutableArray` and it work well when I use it in `viewDidLoad` but I found this problem:

> [UIFont CacheKey count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

when I use it in other places.

I'm newest and I need your help please

```
NSMutableArray *MessageList;

@synthesize _table,newwMessage,addMessage;

extern User *user_selected;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // MessageList =  [NSMutableArray array];
    MessageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // test web Services
    webServices *web= [[webServices alloc] init];
    AppDelegate *app=  (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [web getConversation:app.user_connect.pk :user_selected.pk completion:^(NSMutableArray * ListMessages) {
        MessageList=ListMessages;

          NSLog(@"haut > %d ",MessageList.count);   // work 
               [_table reloadData];
    }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"messagingCell";

       NSLog(@"haut > %d ",MessageList.count);      // don't work 

    PTSMessagingCell * cell = (PTSMessagingCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PTSMessagingCell alloc] initMessagingCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(254/255.0) green:(168/255.0) blue:(198/255.0) alpha:1] ;;
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're probably using ARC.
Because of that, your object is automatically release at the end of viewDidLoad.
And because of your object being released (but not nullified), the memory emplacement has been reused and you're pointing to it. But at that time it's another object

To correct that, you have to add a strong property on your array

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *messageList
```

You can put it in your header file, or in the private category of your .m

And then use your property like this :

```
self.messageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

PS : naming convention said that it's better to start a name with a lower case letter ;) !

Comment: @arbimahdi Did you really use `strong` and not `weak` ? and Did you really use `self.messageList` instead of `messageList` directly ? (This way you will use the setter generated by the property)

Comment: You need to create a property like KIDdAe mentioned. Furthermore, you need to stop accessing/setting the backing variable (MessageList) and start using the property instead (self.PropertyName). Finally, there's really no reason to declare the instance variable; just define a property, and the system will handle managing the backing variable and setters/getters for you (when you call @synthesize propertyName).

Comment: @KIDdAe : it work well now, i changed weak to strong and i should use self.messageList in all the class. thank you :)